# How can you change the order of the values of every field in a structure without knowing the amount of fields? (MatLab)

Tags: matlab, structure

> Write a function called `sortStruct` that takes in a structure array
>          and then sorts the structure array by the values in the inputted field.
>          If the values are numeric, then the function sorts them from lowest to
>          highest. If the values are characters, then the function sorts the
>          *words* alphabetically with case mattering (e.g. 'Apples' is before
>          'apples'). If the field does not exist in the structure array, then the
>          function returns the string 'Invalid Field Name'.

Here is what I have so far:

```
function [ structsort ] = sortStruct( strucArray, fname )

if isfield(strucArray, fname) ~= '1'
    structsort = 'Invalid Field Name';
end

i = class(fname);

for i = 'double'
    [sorteddoub inddoub] = sort(fname);
    fieldn = fieldnames(strucArray);
    num = length(fieldn);
    strucArray = setfield(strucArray, fname, sorteddoub);

    structsort = setfield(strucArray, fieldn, fieldn(inddoub));
end

for i = 'char'
    [sortedchar indchar] = sort(char2num(fname(1)));
end
```

Comment: Any pointers would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be on the right track, aside from the syntax errors. So a few comments:

- `ISFIELD` returns true/false
- a better way to test the data type of variables is using is** family of functions: `ISNUMERIC`, `ISSTRUCT`, `ISCHAR`, ...
- you should read on the difference between `if`/`for`/... constructs
- the `SORT` function can handle both vector of numbers and cell array of strings. You should use that functionality (read the documentation page first)
- The syntax for accessing structure fields dynamically is: `structName.(dynamicExpression)`

Having said that, here is how I would write such a function:

```
function structSorted = sortStruct(structArray, fname)
    if ~isfield(structArray,fname)
        error('Invalid Field Name')
    end

    if isnumeric( structArray(1).(fname) )
        data = [structArray.(fname)];
    else
        data = {structArray.(fname)};
    end

    [~,order] = sort(data);
    structSorted = structArray(order);
end
```

And lets test the function with some random array of structures:

```
%# lets build some array of structures
chars = char(97:122);
str = cellstr( chars(ceil(numel(chars).*rand(10,6))) );
[s(1:10).str] = str{:};
num = num2cell(rand(10,1));
[s(1:10).num] = num{:};

%# sort according to a field
s_str = sortStruct(s, 'str');
s_num = sortStruct(s, 'num');
%#s_err = sortStruct(s, 'zzzzz');

%# compare the two sorted array of structures
myS2C = @(s) squeeze(struct2cell(s))';   %'# a helper function to show results
myS2C(s_str)
myS2C(s_num)
```

Sorting by the field `str` gave:

```
>> myS2C(s_str)
ans = 
    'cbawoj'    [ 0.10401]
    'fqwiek'    [ 0.17567]
    'fskvdc'    [ 0.46847]
    'hezhbh'    [ 0.33585]
    'kyeaxv'    [ 0.67539]
    'ooumrm'    [ 0.20895]
    'qbnqit'    [ 0.90515]
    'wcwyjs'    [0.056705]
    'wdyhlz'    [ 0.52189]
    'ytdoze'    [ 0.91213]
```

while sorting by the field `num`:

```
>> myS2C(s_num)
ans = 
    'wcwyjs'    [0.056705]
    'cbawoj'    [ 0.10401]
    'fqwiek'    [ 0.17567]
    'ooumrm'    [ 0.20895]
    'hezhbh'    [ 0.33585]
    'fskvdc'    [ 0.46847]
    'wdyhlz'    [ 0.52189]
    'kyeaxv'    [ 0.67539]
    'qbnqit'    [ 0.90515]
    'ytdoze'    [ 0.91213]
```